# Spring security with database and multiple roles?

Tags: spring-security

I'm trying to make an application using spring 3.0.
Now I've decided to try my hand at spring-security and hibernate.
I've already seen that it's possible to back it with a databasem and I've seen a reference to defining your own queries?

Now the problem I have is that the tutorials I've been finding aren't too clear and that they assume that a user can only have one role. I want to give some users multiple roles.

So I was thinking about a database scheme along the lines of:

**User:**

- user_id
- username
- password
- registrationDate

**User_Role:**

- user_id
- role_id

**Role:**

- role_id
- rolename

Now I was wondering if anyone had some pointers to some usefull tutorials/advice/comments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to implement your own [UserDetails](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html) (supports multiple roles for each user). This custom UserDetails implementation is then returned by your own [UserDetailsService](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html) implementation that's injected on your [daoAuthenticationProvider](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/dao/DaoAuthenticationProvider.html).

See also my answer @ [Spring Security 3 database authentication with Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683308/spring-security-3-database-authentication-with-hibernate/2701722#2701722) for a complete example.

Comment: I understood the authentication part from database. But how do we assign the roles from the database? Can you answer my question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893061/how-to-dynamically-decide-intercept-url-access-attribute-value-in-spring-securi

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
public class CustomUserService implements UserDetailsService {

   private UserDao userDao;

   public CustomUserService(UserDao u) {
      userDao = u;
   }

   public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
      CustomUser user = userDao.getUser(username);
      if (user == null)
         throw new UserNotFoundException("User "+username+" does not exist");
      return user;
   }
}
```

And your UserDao implementation is a simple DAO that can easily use hibernate annotations and assign multple roles to your CustomUser object.  Pretty basic.