# Spring security : Multiple roles for a single user

Tags: spring-security

My application needs me to define multiple roles for a single user .

I have read [Spring security with database and multiple roles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707706/spring-security-with-database-and-multiple-roles) .

Why should we implement our own UserDetails ? Existing one contains

```
Collection getAuthorities();
```

Also is there any reference or tutorial which I can follow for implementing multiple roles for a single user ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accepted answer to the post you have referenced doesn't seem correct to me. You don't have to create your own `UserDetailsService` implementation for this. Multiple roles are already supported. See [JdbcDaoImpl](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/jdbc/JdbcDaoImpl.html). You have to just make sure that `authoritiesByUsernameQuery` matches with your database set up. By default its value is `select username,authority from authorities where username = ?`. This query is executed by `loadUserAuthorities` method that loads all authorities.

Comment: I tried this and instead of splitting ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER into 2 roles, I got the whole string as a single role "ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER" which needless to say does not work

Comment: @markbaldy I am not sure if I got the issue. Can you add code to show what you have tried?

Comment: Using your solution the whole string was returned as a single permission: "ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER", instead of ["ROLE_ADMIN","ROLE_USER"]. I did need to implement my own UserDetailsService.

Comment: I guess I am trying to understand where do you get that string. The loadUserAuthorities method of JdbcDaoImpl returns a list of GrantedAuthority.

Answer (score 2):

In case anybody is interested in a custom UserDetailsService for comma-separated authorities:

```
@Component
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Resource
    private AccountService accounts;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        Account account = accounts.findByUsername(username);
        if(null == account) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User " + username + " not found.");
        }

        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<SimpleGrantedAuthority>();
        String[] authStrings = account.getAuthorities().split(", ");
        for(String authString : authStrings) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authString));
        }

        UserDetails ud = new User(account.getUsername(), account.getPassword(), authorities);
        return ud;
    }

}
```

Now you can have something like this in the db:

```
+----+-----------------------+----------+----------+
| id | authorities           | password | username |
+----+-----------------------+----------+----------+
|  1 | ROLE_ADMIN            | 123qwe   | markm    |
|  2 | ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER | 123qwe   | kemika   |
+----+-----------------------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: how exactly do you config spring config file to support asign multiple roles to a single user?

Answer (score 0):

Spring security supports more-than-one roles **out-of-the-box!**

So, to save all of you fine folks a ton of time:

**One must insert multiple entries for the same user:** 
[image]
That was in MySQL Workbench, with MySQL 5.7.24
Also other environments - in case you wondering which version to reproduce that result:

```
    <!-- Inherit defaults from Spring Boot -->
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- optional, it brings useful tags to display spring security stuff -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Then to verify I made this page and: 
[image]

Here's the example code for displaying and verifying the logged in account's authorities:

```
<div data-layout-fragment="content" class="content">
    <div class="row mt-4">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2>Show Authorities Glance</h2>
        <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            Logged user: <span data-sec-authentication="name">Bob</span>
            Roles: <span data-sec-authentication="principal.authorities">[ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN]</span>
            <div data-sec-authorize="isAuthenticated()">
            This content is only shown to authenticated users.
            </div>
            <div data-sec-authorize="hasRole('ROLE_USER')">
            This content is only shown to ROLE_USER.
            </div>
            <div data-sec-authorize="hasRole('ROLE_EMPLOYEE')">
            This content is only shown to ROLE_EMPLOYEE.
            </div>
            <div data-sec-authorize="hasRole('ROLE_FOUNDER')">
            This content is only shown to ROLE_FOUNDER.
            </div>
            <div data-sec-authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
            This content is only shown to ROLE_ADMIN.
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--<p>-->
    <!--<a data-th-href="@{/add-authority}">Add a new authority</a>-->
<!--</p>-->
</div>
```

Oh and this last view contains thymeleaf and not only the standard one also the layout dialect. Just in case you would like to try it out also need this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Or get ride of the layout fragment tag:

```
data-layout-fragment="content"
```