# Different logins when coming from different urls

Tags: java, security, spring, authentication, spring-security

I have an application with uses a custom authenticationManager for the login. It just search on a table called Users.

```
<sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDAOImpl">
        <sec:password-encoder hash="sha" />
    </sec:authentication-provider>
</sec:authentication-manager>
```

The problem is that now I need to do another login which must search on the table "ExternalUsers".

The application would work in this way:

1. If the request comes from an url like /external/** I need to go through an a authenticationManager2 which searches on the table "ExternalUsers". These users can only access to /external/** urls
2. It the request comes from another url I need to go through an authenticationManager1 (the one I have right now) which search on the table Users. These users can access all the urls but the ones which matches the pattern /external/**

There may be users in the tables Users and ExternalUsers **with the same username**. This is the reason why I need to set different logins depending on the url where it comes from. Both logins must be in the same application.

Is it possible in Spring to configure two different authenticationManager each one depending on the request url where it comes?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think, that spring provide it out of the box. But you can implement your own Authentication Provider (implement `AuthenticationProvider` Interface) , that delegate the authentication to one two standard spring Authentication Provider depending on some logic.

Comment: But how can the implementation of the authenticationManager know the url of the request?

Comment: @Javi: my fault: Authentication Provider not Manager

Answer (score 1):

A future version of Spring Security may allow multiple authentication managers but until then some customizations will do the job.

I think Ralph's answer is in right direction. You can add another http element ([Spring Security 3.1](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-form-and-basic)) to capture external/** url pattern and add your custom login filter to pass a different token (can be named as ExternalUserPasswordAuthenticationToken that extends AbstractAuthenticationToken) to authentication provider. See [Configuring Spring Security 3.x to have multiple entry points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783063/configuring-spring-security-3-x-to-have-multiple-entry-point) and my answer to [Authenticate user using external webservice in grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270054/authenticate-user-using-external-webservice-in-grails) to develop your own tokens and providers.

Another way, which I would not recommend, is to set up a Voter for /external/** url pattern that does the authentication job.