# multiple <security:http> section in spring security configuration file

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am trying to configure 2 different authentication types in my spring security xml file. One for BASIC and the other Kerberos, both of them work fine when when only one is configured but getting the following error when configuring both in the same file

org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Duplicate  element detected

I am using Spring Security 3.0.5 and the xml schema is

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">
```

Can someone advice how to configure multiple security:http section and authentication managers in one application.

Comment: Post your configuration...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add multiple authentication providers like in this [post](http://www.javacodebook.com/2013/07/03/spring-security-multiple-authentication-providers/)?

Then you'll have one security tag but with multiple authentication options.

EDIT

I've found similar problem at [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783063/configuring-spring-security-3-x-to-have-multiple-entry-points). The author wants to authenticate with LDAP and database.