# Spring REST security - Secure different URLs differently

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have working REST API under Spring 4 using Basic authentication. These REST services are under /api/v1/** URL. However, I want to add another set of REST endpoints under different url /api/v2/**, but protected with token-based authentication.

Is it possible to do this with one servlet ? How to configure Spring Security to use different forms of authentication for different URLs ?

Thank you.

Comment: You should be able to have more than just one entry-point in your spring security applicationContext where you can specify your intercept url patterns.

Comment: You mean more protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) methods, each for every URL pattern ? Can you give me an example of what you mean, please ? Thank you.

Comment: I have only worked with xml based setup of spring security, and from my knowledge its possible to have setup multiple <http> tags, with different entry-points and its own set of intercept-urls. I could try putting something  basic together if you want.

Comment: Of course, I'd like to. IT doesn't matter, I will probably be able to translate it into programmatic configuration. Thank you.

Comment: It seems like, at least from spring-security 3.x that duplicate http elements is not allowed. I was sure i'd seen something like that once, must have been something from an older version i guess. I am sorry i was unable to help

Comment: Please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783063/configuring-spring-security-3-x-to-have-multiple-entry-points
You can configure multiple entry points for your application.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here's a code sample in Java config that uses `UserDetailsService` and has different security configurations for different URL endpoints:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .antMatcher("/api/v1/**")
                    .httpBasic()
                        .realmName("API")
                        .and()
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/api/v1/**").authenticated();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class ApiTokenSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .antMatcher("/api/v2/**")
                    /* other config options go here... */
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: My use case is little different. Is it possible to configure `/api/**` to use basic authentication and remaining application to use form login?

Comment: Yes. Use `http.antMatcher("/api/**")` in the first line of API security config and `http.requestMatcher(new NegatedRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/**")))` in config for the rest of the application.

Comment: What if I want to user different userDetailsService for each end-point?

Comment: WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is deprecated now.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to do the same thing. I have two APIs. `/urgent/` and `/home/`. I want to protect first with httpBasic and second with oAuthLogin. Rest I want to default to formLogin. 
However, it's not working. When I'm authenticated with basic, it's also showing oauth protected response. When I hit the `/home/` first, it is throwing error. 
Individually both of configs were working. It got wrong when I tried to mix them. 
Please help.

https://pastebin.com/19cVNYmY