# Spring Security with both "Basic Auth" and SiteMinder filters

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a Spring Boot web application that serves up both web content and exposes REST Services. I want to protect the REST Services with "Basic Auth" and the web content with SiteMinder. I'm using Spring Security version 4.2.3.

My problem is that I'm seeing the error:

[9/13/18 16:11:20:711 EDT] 000000bc SystemOut     O 2018-09-13 16:11:20.710 ERROR 19260 --- [ebContainer : 1] o.s.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter     : Forwarding to error page from request [/services/ews/meetinglocations] due to exception [SM_USER header not found in request.]

Both when I attempt to call the REST Service from PostMan, and when I attempt to load web content from a web browser. ***I expect to see the error when loading content from the web browser because I don't have SiteMinder set up yet, but why am I not able to call the REST Service?***

Here's the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class:

```
package eacmanager.security;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.NegatedRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import eacmanager.utility.ApplicationConstants;

@Configuration
@Component
@EnableWebSecurity
public class CustomWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(CustomWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.class.getName());

    private PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider preAuthenticatedProvider;


    public CustomWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {
        super();

        UserDetailsService userDetailsService = new CustomUserDetailsService();
        UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper<PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken> wrapper = 
                new UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper<PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken>(userDetailsService);

        preAuthenticatedProvider = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider();
        preAuthenticatedProvider.setPreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService(wrapper);
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(preAuthenticatedProvider);
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity) throws Exception {
        webSecurity.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/assets/**", "/eacmanager/error.html");
    }


    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Creating in memory Authentication");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
          .withUser("user").password("pass")
          .roles("USER");
    }


//  Use of multiple URLs to protect:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33037559/spring-rest-security-secure-different-urls-differently

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            LOGGER.info("Creating SiteMinder filter 4");

            RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter siteMinderFilter = new RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter();
            siteMinderFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());

            http
                .addFilter(siteMinderFilter)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/eacmanager/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .hasRole(ApplicationConstants.SITE_MINDER_AUTHORITY);
        }
    }


    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

        @Autowired
        private EACManagerBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            LOGGER.info("Creating REST Services filter");

            http
              .requestMatcher(new NegatedRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/eacmanager/**")))
              .authorizeRequests()                      
              .antMatchers("/eacmanager/services/**")   
              .permitAll()                              
              .anyRequest()                             
              .authenticated()                          
              .and()
              .httpBasic()                              
              .realmName(ApplicationConstants.SITE_REALM_NAME)
              .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint); 
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterAfter(new CustomFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }


    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

If I reverse the order of the two filters, I can call the REST Service using "Basic Auth", but the web content gets served up ***WITHOUT*** the SiteMinder error. I should be getting the SiteMinder header missing error.

Comment: @user2092870, would you please take a look at this issue? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @user:2092870, would you please take a look at this issue?