# Disable login page redirect for specific url but still require it's authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Application is based on Spring Boot and provides a web confgiuration gui.
By default, if a user is not authorized, he gets redirected to `/login` an gets redirected to the desired page on successful authorization.

Now I need to provide an API endpoint for intergration of a different software `/cid`.

I want to disable redirect to `/login` for this specific `/cid/` endpoint but still require basic autorization header.

Right now I have the following and I understant this config as: "prevent all requests and redirect them to `/login` except `/cid` and all children of `/js/` and `/css/`." and it seems that I am wrong.

```
http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/cid", "/js/**", "/css/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login");
```

How to configure Spring Security to "require authorization for `/cid`, require authorization and redirect to `/login` everything else"?

I really got lost in documentation of Spring.

Comment: you implement a custom `ServerAuthenticationSuccessHandler`and set it using `authenticationSuccessHandler` and no i dont have a code example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring REST security - Secure different URLs differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33037559/spring-rest-security-secure-different-urls-differently)