# Do I need a separate JWT Filter for Multiple Logins?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

The User login is working well but I want to add a Customer Module to the project. I know that I need to write a custom UserDetails class to get the customer Username but I want to ask if I need to write another Custom JWT filter for the Customer Login validation. Presently this is the Filter class that I have for User Login. I have added a username and password field to the Customer entity.

```
@Component
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;
    
    @Autowired
    private UserAccountService myUserDetailsService;
    
    
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        final String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        String username = null;
        String jwtToken = null;
        
        if (requestTokenHeader != null) {
            jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);
            try {
                username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                System.out.println("Unable to get JWT Token");
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                System.out.println("JWT Token has expired");
            }
        } 

        
        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
      
            UserDetails userDetails = this.myUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwtToken, userDetails)) {
            
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                
            String authorities = userDetails.getAuthorities().stream().map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                    .collect(Collectors.joining());
             System.out.println("Authorities granted : " + authorities);
                    
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Not Valid Token");
            }

        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }


}
```

As you can see the Filter is using the custom UserDetails to verify the username . How do I add the Customer userdetails service to the filter ? This is my first multiple login project please be  lenient with me.

Comment: Would you mind providing a link to the tutorial you followed to build this filter? Also, have you considered using [Resource Server support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/5.6/servlet/oauth2/oauth2-resourceserver.html)? It allows you to validate JWTs without writing a custom filter implementation, and is built into Spring Security.

Answer (score 0):

it looks to me like you already did.

```java
@Autowired
private UserAccountService myUserDetailsService;
```

But I would suggest using a Constructor instead of @Autowired. Spring will fill in the constructor parameters just the same. This could be very slim when you use the lombok library as well.
Using a constructor also makes mocking this a bit easier for testing.

---

##### Updated as discussed in the comments:

```java
@Log //another lombok thing
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class JwtRequestFilter extends Filter{
    
    private final JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;
    
    private final UserAccountService myUserDetailsService;
    
    private final CustomerAccountService myCustomerDetailsService;

    private static final String AUTH_HEADER = "authorization";
    
    @Override
    protected void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String tokenHeader = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getHeader(AUTH_HEADER);
        if(hasValue(tokenHeader) && tokenHeader.toLowerCase().startsWith("bearer ")){
            jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);

            String username;
            String jwtToken;
 
            try {
                username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken);
        
                if (uSecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {

                    UserDetails userDetails = myUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
                    if(isNull(userDetails)){
                        userDetails = myCustomerDetailsService.loadCustomerByUsername(username);
                    }
                    if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwtToken, userDetails)) {
                        var token = createSecurityToken(userDetails);
                        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(token);
                    } else {
                        throw new RuntimeException("Not a Valid Token.");
                    }
                } else {
                    log.info("Authorization already present");
                }
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                throw new("Unable to get JWT Token",e);
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                throw new("JWT Token has expired",e);
            }
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("No valid authorization header found.");
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken createSecurityToken(UserDetails userDetails){
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
        log.info("Authorities granted : {}", userDetails.getAuthorities());
        token.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
        return token;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much @3Fish the autowired UserAccountService class is for Users . Now I have a CustomerAccountService too for customer Login .  How do I make this single Filter class validate for both service.

Comment: You could just add its service as another injected dependency like you do with the myUserDetailsService or add another filter class that does the same. 

The second approach might have more code, but if both cases are different Concerns, they should be implemented separately as well. This will keep your classes short and maintainable.
You can define the order of execution for all filters with the @Order(<some number>) annotation.

Also, you might want to move the `chain.doFilter(request, response);` to the "valid" section or invalid requests will be processed further too.

Answer (score 0):

Differentiate between user and customer while logging. Accordingly, call the different service to get user details. More can be found here.
[Spring Security user authentication against customers and employee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57935197/spring-security-user-authentication-against-customers-and-employee)

Comment: Also go through this  https://turreta.com/2016/12/26/spring-boot-spring-security-with-multiple-login-forms-and-user-types/

Answer (score 0):

1. **How do I add the Customer userdetails service to the filter?**: inject it as you did with `UserAccountService`. If you do this way, you're using 1 filter (and of course, this filter is in 1 `SecurityFilterChain`), you could basically implement your filter like: trying to validate your user by `myUserDetailsService` and if it's not successful, continue with `myCustomerDetailsService`.
2. For **multiple login project**. The second way you could do is using 2 `SecurityFilterChain`. UserJwtFilter for 1 `SecurityFilterChain` and CustomJwtFilter for 1 `SecurityFilterChain` for example. People usually do this way for different login mechanisms Basic, OAuth2, SAML2. E.g:

- Basic Authentication:

```java
@Configuration
@Order(2)
public class BasicAuthenticationFilterChain extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .requestMatchers()
                    .antMatchers("/login", "/logout")
                .and()
```

- OAuth2 Authentication:

```java
@Configuration
@Order(3)
public class OAuth2AuthenticationFilterChain extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .requestMatchers()
                    .antMatchers("/oauth")
                .and()
```

In this case when a request with "/login" it'll be directed to `BasicAuthenticationFilterChain`, and a request with "/oauth" will go to `OAuth2AuthenticationFilterChain`. About `Order`: the lower is the higher priority and once the request's processed with a `SecurityFilterChain`, it won't go to another `SecurityFilterChain`. You can implement your project this way.

**Conclusion**: There are a lot of ways you can implement your idea with spring security, it depends on your choice.