# Any good tutorials/examples for the Spring3 Security Framework?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

Can someone please help me out, I am just getting into Spring3, Spring3 MVC Validation and Hibernate

Can someone please tell me of  any good tutorials/examples for the Spring3 Security Framework?

I would love to find a example that looks up the user information from a database.  please help me out!  thanks.  SPRING3

Comment: If you search in this forum, you will find several examples and links to other sites. Maybe you could start from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683308/spring-security-3-database-authentication-with-hibernate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would visit the [Getting Started](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/start-here.html) link of spring security and follow the steps mentioned therein, specifically

- deploy the sample application
- follow the petclinic tutorial

Then move on to links suggested by others.

Answer (score 0):

Hope these links would be usefull for you:

- http://krams915.blogspot.com/2010/12/spring-security-mvc-integration.html
- http://krams915.blogspot.com/2010/12/spring-security-mvc-integration_18.html
- http://www.javabeat.net/articles/176-spring-security-30-1.html

And of course official reference: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html

Also some links can be found here: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/articles.html