# How do I do HTTP basic auth using Struts 2/ Spring 3?

Tags: java, web-services, struts2

I am writing a RESTful web service, and certain APIs requires user identity authorization. Since HTTP basic auth is just enough for my requirements, I decide to use it.

I want to check user credentials supplied by my API user against a MySQL database table storing those credentials.

How do I actually achieve that using Struts 2/ Spring 3?

Comment: I have not exp with web-services but i believe you have to expose some kind of method to your web-service consumer where they can send request with there credentials.So it should be a simple method may be in your action class calling a userAuth method from service passing it the required userid and password and this method should be responsible to send you back a flag if the user is valid or not

Comment: Yes, that exactly what I want to do, and I know how to do this if my API user send username/password through parameters in their GET/POST methods. What I don't know it how to do the authorization not by sending credentials directly in parameters but in the "Authorization" header in HTTP headers, since this is more a convention for a web service.

Comment: I mean I don't know how to retrieve the `Authorization` header and parse them and check against a database. There must be some code doing this in Struts2 / Spring3, I just don't know where it is and how to use them.

Comment: not sure can help you much but there is a rest plugin that works with Struts 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use spring-security for that. I just did it, following the tutorial from http://syntx.co/languages-frameworks/adding-http-basic-auth-to-restful-services-in-java-and-spring/

To authenticate against a database, you probably need to make your own authentication-provider; there is an example on: [Spring Security 3 database authentication with Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683308/spring-security-3-database-authentication-with-hibernate)

In short:

**1) Add spring-security in pom.xml:**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>       

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

**2) Add filter to web.xml:**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
```

(you also need the spring ContextLoaderListener but if you are already using spring it's probably already in your web.xml)

**3) Update your spring xml configuration**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    ...
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    ...
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <security:http auto-config='true'>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <security:http-basic />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <!-- this is an demo example with hardcoded username and password -->
            <security:user-service>
                <security:user name="..." password="..." authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
    ....
</beans>
```

My example does not show how to authenticate against a database: as I said above, it's already covered in [Spring Security 3 database authentication with Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683308/spring-security-3-database-authentication-with-hibernate) (did not tried that as I just need hardcoded username & password for now).