# Integration of Spring Security 3 authentication with Hibernate 3(JPA) annotation

Tags: hibernate, spring-security

I am looking some example for **integration of latest Spring framework security with Hibernate** based on annotation( ie JPA) with user credential from the DB. How can I do this? can I go for password encoding and decoding with Spring?

One of the solution available is with link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683308/spring-security-3-database-authentication-with-hibernate/2701722#2701722) but this is based on Spring 2.5 with XML configuration. I want to avoid xml and use annotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Spring source documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html). Everything you needed is given on documentation. And yeah! you can go with password encoding and decoding with spring. Just write your encoding class which will extend the org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.MessageDigestPasswordEncoder.

```
public class MyPassEncoder extends org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.MessageDigestPasswordEncoder
{
   MyPassEncoder(){
   super("MD5");
}
public String encodePassword(String rawPass, Object salt) {
   String encPass =  super.encodePassword(rawPass, salt);
   return encPass;
}
}
```

Comment: there is no example given in that document for Spring security with Hibernate based on Annotation concept.

Comment: download examples from spring security documentation - chapter no. 4     http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#sample-apps