# Spring security roles

Tags: spring-security

I have user roles tables in my database, which contains roles like 'ROLE_ADMIN' and 'ROLE_USER', and in applicationContext-security.xml, I defined the filterSecurityInterceptor as:

```
  <s:filter-chain pattern="/rpc/adminService"
    filters="
        authenticationProcessingFilter,
        filterSecurityInterceptor"/>

  <s:filter-chain pattern="/rpc/**"
    filters="
        concurrentSessionFilter, 
        httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter,
        authenticationProcessingFilter,
        rememberMeProcessingFilter,
        anonymousProcessingFilter,
        exceptionTranslationFilter,
        filterSecurityInterceptor" />

  <s:filter-chain pattern="/j_spring_security*"
    filters="
        concurrentSessionFilter, 
        httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter,
        logoutFilter,
        authenticationProcessingFilter,
        rememberMeProcessingFilter,
        anonymousProcessingFilter" />

  <s:filter-chain pattern="/**" filters="none" />
</s:filter-chain-map>
```

```
  <bean id="filterSecurityInterceptor" class="org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <property name="accessDecisionManager" ref="accessDecisionManager" />
    <property name="objectDefinitionSource">
      <s:filter-invocation-definition-source>
        <s:intercept-url pattern="/rpc/userService" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <s:intercept-url pattern="/rpc/adminService**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
        <s:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
      </s:filter-invocation-definition-source>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.providers.ProviderManager">
    <property name="sessionController" ref="concurrentSessionController" />
    <property name="providers">
      <list>
        <ref bean="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider" />
        <ref bean="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
      </list>
    </property>
  </bean>

 <bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.providers.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="accountRepository" />
    <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder" />
  </bean>
```

However, when I tried to access some resource as admin user, it got rejected, complained as:

```
An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
```

How can I convert a role that defined in the database to a role that recognized by securityContext?

Comment: It sounds like you aren't setting up authentication properly. Please show how you have configured the filter chain.

Comment: @LukeTaylor:i've updated the code to include the filter chain. thx

Answer (score 2):

You have no `HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter` in your filter chain for `/rpc/adminService`. You haven't said what the request URL is when you're seeing the problem, but if you access that exact URL there will be no security context provided for the request.

Spring Security filter chains should **always** have this filter included.

I would also beware of your

```
<s:filter-chain pattern="/**" filters="none" />
```

since anything that is not matched by the previous patterns will not have a security context.

Answer (score 0):

You have this in your configuration right?

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="accountRepository">
        <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Have you looked into this:
[spring-security-3-database-authentication-with-hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683308/spring-security-3-database-authentication-with-hibernate)

I am using this for simple testing:

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" >
    <authentication-provider>
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                users-by-username-query =
                    "SELECT username, password, CASE Status WHEN 1 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END as enabled
                        FROM User
                        WHERE username = ?"
                authorities-by-username-query=
                    "SELECT username, CASE role WHEN 1 THEN 'ROLE_USER' WHEN 2 THEN 'ROLE_ADMIN' ELSE 'ROLE_GUEST' END as authorities
                        FROM User
                        WHERE username = ?" />       
        </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Comment: i tried this but got error as "Cannot locate BeanDefinitionDecorator for element [jdbc-user-service]"??? <bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.providers.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
  
    <s:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="accountRepository"
  users-by-username-query = "select EMAIL, PASSWORD, ENABLED, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME from USERS where EMAIL=?"
     authorities-by-username-query="select u.USER_ID, ur.ROLE_NAME from USERS u, USER_ROLES ur where u.USER_ID = ur.USER_ID and u.EMAIL=?"
    />