# Spring WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter API

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I've been playing around with Spring for the last few days and things are getting to be fun. I'm working with security right now and I've run into a slight snag. Basically, I want the authentication to happen via an API call rather than a form. Is there a neat way to do this?

I've extended the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter like so -

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/openapi/**").hasRole("USER")
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http
                .formLogin()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/hello")
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authManagerBuilder.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");

        authManagerBuilder.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("manager").password("password").roles("MANAGER");
    }
}
```

Is there a way to pick up the the usernames and passwords from a database and can I perform the authentication with an API call?

Comment: This can maybe help you http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-using-database/

Comment: @ant - I did see that one. I've tried replicating it as code in the configure() but am unable to do so correctly.

Comment: Try basic authentication insted of formlogin authentication.

Answer (score -1):

[Spring Security 3 database authentication with Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683308/spring-security-3-database-authentication-with-hibernate)

This seems promising. It needs a custom authentication manager created.

Answer (score -1):

You can use jdbc authentication with Java configuration as described in the reference http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-authentication-jdbc